# Python - wait for sysinputs

Tags: python

So I´m trying to create a python backend script for an electron app. I want to be able to continually pass system inputs to the python file, and have it run a function whenever the system input changes. I don´t want to have to run the python script each time as it takes a few seconds to load modules and data and just slows down the app.

I can´t find a good description anywhere on how to do this.

```
import sys
sysArg = []   

def sysPrint(sysArgs):
    print(sysArgs[1:])

while True:
    if sys.argv <> sysArg:
        sysPrint(sys.argv)
    sysArg = sys.argv
```

This doesn´t work for me and also a "while True" loop doesn´t feel very safe CPU wise.
I´m also thinking that sys.argv might not be the right choice as that is perhaps only generated when calling the Python script?

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your question, you can just redirect the system output to a file,use `nohup` run program as a background process.

like this:

```
nohup some_program &> output.log" &
```

And then you can handle the output file like this:

```
import time

def tail(f):
    f.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output_file= open("output.log","r")
    for line in tail(output_file):
        print(line)
```